# Hadoop installation + Virtualization enabled 64 bit CPU

Tags: hadoop, 64-bit, cpu, virtualization, bios

I have Windows 7 HP Pavilion dv6 note book, but it didn't support for virtualization (as show in figure there is no any option on BIOS).

[image: BIOS setup]

With this configuration, I can not install Cloudera [QuickStart VMs](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/quickstart_vms/cdh-5-3-x.html) .

Due to this issue now I need to clarify the following points,

1) For installing Hadoop, does it need a CPU with **virtualization** support?
   - If yes, are there any options for install on older CPUs without virtualization support?

2) For installing Hadoop, whether the CPU should be **64 bit** ? 
   - If yes, is there any options for install on 32 bit CPUs

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Hadoop is written (mostly) in Java and does not need CPU virtualization support to run. Java works on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

(2) Hadoop runs on either 32-bit or 64-bit CPUs, but matching what your OS is running is probably easiest.

Also, CPU Virtualization support is not strictly required to run Virtual Machines. I've ran both VMWare and VirtualBox VMs on multiple machines without a problem. CPU Virtualization support simply improves performance of VMs running on a host.